# Bank Has Emailed My Social Security Number

Tags: encryption, tls, email, identity-theft, pdf

I'm in the middle of getting a mortgage.  Just now, my bank sent over an e-mail (sent to my Gmail account) with a bunch of .pdf attachments of documents I'm supposed to sign and return.  The first thing I noticed is that many of these .pdf files were pre-populated with my personal information.  The .pdf files were not encrypted or password protected.

All sorts of personal information was in the documents - not just my SSN by my name/DOB/address/bank account numbers/etc/etc....

Before I go off the deep-end here, can we just confirm that there is no such thing as a `secure` e-mail with unencrypted text/attachments?  My understanding is that, best case scenario - they used TLS/SSL and it was encrypted in transit but that the encryption would only be between the sender and Google's server.  So, somewhere, at one of Google's data farms, there is a .pdf with all of my personal information in it, that is not encrypted or protected.  Does that sound about right?

In the message headers I can see

> Received...by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id.....(version=TLS1_2...)

So it seems it was sent with TLS, which is good.  But are the attachments/visible to my mail provider?

Comment: There is a such thing! It's called encryption :) You should talk about your concerns with the bank manager. There are a lot of red flags being raised here. If this is how they handle PII in email, think of how they handle the rest of your information.

Comment: *But are the attachments/visible to my mail provider?* - yes, Google automatically scan GMail messages to provide advertising and Google Now features ([source](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6603?hl=en)) and GMail engineers can potentially access any account as part of necessary work, with oversight ([source](http://www.labnol.org/tech/can-google-employees-read-gmail/19572/)). *somewhere, at one of Google's data farms* - many data farms, and backup tapes [source](http://talkincloud.com/the-solution-to-the-gmail-glitch-tape-backup)

Comment: You should make that an answer @tesselatingheckler

Comment: In all reality, it may be time to look for a new bank. If your current bank is this careless with your personal information then how long until something worse happens. There are very strict rules when handling information like Social Security Numbers and other personal information regarding clients. If they had the ability to email those documents to you they could have just as easily set up a secure signing like Docusign to accomplish this task rather than risk your info.

Comment: You should consider naming the bank that felt this was a reasonable practice.

Comment: How would this not be a violation of PCI req 4.2? as the social security ## is part of protected cardholder information.

Comment: @John PCI DSS does not list SSN as "Cardholder Data" and in any case PCI DSS only applies to payment cards, payment-card transactions, and payment-card accounts, hence the name "Payment Card Industry DSS". A mortgage is not a payment card/txn/account. What *does* apply in the US (at least theoretically) is Graham-Leach-Bliley https://epic.org/privacy/glba/  .

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I stand corrected. Would you say to contact a lawyer or the FTC and report this violation?

Comment: @John *If US* (I don't know for anywhere else) I wouldn't bother with a lawyer unless (you think) you can prove big-dollar damages, since a civil action will take probably 10-15 years and cost a lot, or if you can establish they do this for *many* people and find a lawyer who'll pursue a class action on contingency. I would report to FTC, although they seem to focus on intentional violations (like selling the whole database) which are probably larger-scale and definitely easier to prove. I might try CFPB, although they don't have a track record yet. And I definitely would complain to ...

Comment: .. whichever Federal "functional" regulator applies to the given FI; OCC has a nice lookup at http://www.helpwithmybank.gov/national-banks/national-banks.html . They won't act on an individual complaint, but if they get a pattern it'll affect the scoping and perhaps frequency of their examinations of the bank -- and bank management's first priority is *don't offend the regulator because that can cost us big money*.

Comment: Quit giving banks your email address :) - make them send it postal mail.

Comment: I had a similar problem when purchasing a house this year. The bank, the realtor, the insurance company, everybody defaulted to sending sensitive information as email attachments. To be honest, it terrified me, but the process of buying a house moves so fast that I didn't have time to complain without possibly losing my bid on the property. There's good money to be made in creating an easy to use solution for this problem that financial institutions will adapt.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to safely encrypt email, but you would know (without looking at the headers) since there must be a way for you to authenticate yourself as the receiver.  If they put a signature cert on the email, that does not mean that it is encrypted, that only provides a way for you to confirm the identity of the sender.  The encryption must be performed in addition, usually in the form of an add-on to your email client or a server to server encryption in a business environment.  If there were any health questions in there, you could be looking at a HIPAA violation.  You should question the security practices of an entity if this is a normal practice.

Comment: HIPAA only apples to health care providers, insurers, and clearing houses.  Not banks.